# how to remove an unwanted line within pst-asr

Tags: linguistics, pst-asr

I am trying to code a phonological representation with `pst-asr`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node,pst-asr,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\newpsstyle{bigsyls}{extragap=.6ex,unitxgap=true,xgap=3.5ex,ts=0pt ($\times$),sy=5.5ex ($\sigma$) .7ex,ph=-4.5ex (pf)}
\newpsstyle{dashed}{linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt}
\newpsstyle{crossing}{xed=true,xedtype=\xedcirc,style=dashed}
\newpsstyle{dotted}{linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1.2pt,dotsep=1.6pt}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$}
\def\crossing{\pscircle[linestyle=solid,linewidth=.5pt](0,0){.7ex}}%
\newdimen\dimpuba
\newdimen\dimpubb
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\asr[xgap=1.5in, yunit=3em, ts=0 (Pg), sy=0.7 ((), 
tssym=\underline{\hspace{0.5cm}}, sysym=$\times$]
\1{\phantom{A}}
\endasr}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

I am almost there, but there's additional line I can't remove. The line underneath the underscore symbol shouldn't be there, but I can't figure out why it appears. Can someone help me remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That little line comes from the extra leaf you are inserting into the tree (I'm sorry for not using the correct terms here). In this case it's an empty `\phantom{A}` leaf which only gets you the edge from the parent (the `\underline`) to the leaf without the leaf actually being rendered. It seems you are just using this for additional spacing or to comply that the syntax requires some content in this position.

However, the `pst-asr` package already provides an `\X` command for such empty leaves which takes care to remove the spurious edge. You can use it along with other nodes that should have leaves in this position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-asr}

\begin{document}

\asr[xgap=1.5in, yunit=3em, ts=0 (Pg), sy=0.7 ((),tssym=\underline{\hspace{0.5cm}}, sysym=$\times$]
\1\X
\endasr
\hspace{2em}
\asr[xgap=2.5em, yunit=3em, ts=0 (Pg), sy=0.7 ((),tssym=\underline{\hspace{0.5cm}}, sysym=$\times$]
\3A\X B
\endasr

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

On a second thought, the standard tree pattern seems to be `root -- \times -- leaf`. So what you actually may be after is a tree with an empty *root*, not an empty leaf. You are basically rebuilding that pattern by shifting every node one layer to the top.

Having an empty root is much easier to achieve by placing the `\underline` as a leaf node:

```
\asr[xgap=1.5em, yunit=3em, ts=0.1 (Pg), sy=0.7]
{\underline{\hspace{0.5cm}}}A\X \2BC
\endasr
```

[image]